# Number of solutions of "pseudo-polynomials".

Tags: polynomials

Let's call an equation of the form:

$$
\mathcal P=\sum_{i\geq 0} a_ix^{k_i}
$$

A pseudopolynomial if it satisfies:

1. There exists a $q\in \Bbb N$ such that $a_q,a_{q+1},...$ are zero.
2. $a_i,k_i \in \Bbb C$.
3. The equation has $\lfloor k_e \rceil$ solutions, where $k_e$ is the maximum $k_i$ such that $a_i\neq 0$.
4. $1\leq\frac {k_i} i\leq \Psi$ for some $\Psi$.

What is a $\Phi$ such that $\frac {k_i} i\geq \Phi$ makes the expression a non pseudopolynomial?

Comment: You can express any power series with $k_i=i$ by making the coefficients of the unused powers 0. Therefore we can express any function analytic in a neighborhood of 0 in this way. Thus there could be no zeros, or any finite number of zeros, or a countably infinite number of zeros (the only way we can get an uncountable number is by having it be identically 0).

Comment: @MattSamuel Let me make the question clearer and more specific